# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in python ( using list)

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to use list in this one but I had the bug in the last line `stumarks[CourseID] = [(StuID,marks)]`
Here is my code :

```
courselist = []
class course: 
  def __init__(self,id,name):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
  @classmethod
  def CourseInfo(cls):
    return cls(
     input("Enter the course ID : "),
     input("Enter the course name : ")
      )
def cif():
 for i in range(getNumOfCourses()):
  cse = course.CourseInfo()
  courselist.append(cse)
  
stumarks = []
def MarkInput(): 
 CourseID = input("Enter the course's ID : ")
 if CourseID not in [CourseInfo.id for CourseInfo in courselist]:
       print(" The course's id isn't founded! Please try again!")
 else:
  nm = int(input("Number of student that you want to enter marks: "))
  for i in range(nm):
    while True: 
      StuID = input("Enter a student's ID : ")
      if StuID not in [StudentInfo.id for StudentInfo in studentlist]:
        print("The student's ID isn't founded! Please try again! ")
        continue
      break
    marks = float(input("Enter the mark: "))
    if CourseID in stumarks:
      stumarks[CourseID].append((StuID,marks))
    else:
      stumarks[CourseID] = [(StuID,marks)]
```

Could anyone help me with this one? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `CourseId` is not cast to an integer and is hence treated as a string. Try changing:

```
CourseID = input("Enter the course's ID : ")
```

to

```
CourseID = int(input("Enter the course's ID : "))
```

Comment: I tried it. but then the bug became " IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

Comment: That is because the list is empty. When the list is empty, you need to append to it and not assign. Eg. `stumarks[CourseID] = [(StuID,marks)]` needs to be `stumarks.append([(StuID,marks)])` if the list `stumarks` is empty